# Creating a regular expression that matches a persons name in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have tried parsing names with:

1. `static final String NAME_REGEX="[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)?";`
2. `static final String NAME_REGEX="(([A-Z][a-z]+\\s?)+)|(([A-Z]\.?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\\s?)+)";`

There are even longer,more verbose expressions with which I have tried,I would like to create a small optimal regex for the situation.

I have a list of names that I would like to match using a Java regular expression:

```
B. Jack
B.Jack Black
B Jack Black
B J Black
BJ Black
B.Jack Black
B.J.Black
B. Jack Black
Jack B
Jack B.
Black Jack B.
Jack B
Black J.B
Black JB
Black J B
Jack Black
Black Jack Black
Black J Black
Black J. Black
Black J.Black
Albus P W B Dumbledore
Albus P.W.B. Dumbledore
```

Comment: For those who don't know. It's totally fine to answer one's own question. [See this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: I wrote this in a note-taking app as I solved this problem,I can remove some of the other lesser expressions and the explanation if I have to

Comment: I think you need to formulate a question as a standard SO question which for example includes attempted solutions (+ code). Maybe that's why you got several downvotes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression `(([A-Z]\.?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\.?\s?)+([A-Z]\.?\s?[a-z]*)*)` does it.Please check all expressions on websites like [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/nnj8e) or [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/FYI6x72dvN) before accepting them.

This regular expression,unfortunately also matches:

```
  BlackJack
  Ms Cf Gk
  M Gh M
  Mh G M
  M G Mh
```

and several other similar combinations like that

I found a solution that uses a single regex to match all the test cases specified above.I will go through this,step by step:

This regular expression `([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+` matches a set of words where each word starts with an uppercase charecter,so this would take care of:

```
Jack
Jack Black
Black Jack Black
```

Now you need to be able to match a set of uppercase charecters followed optionally by a `.` and/or a space.In regular expression syntax `.` has a special meaning,it matches any single charecter,so `.+` would match any string there is.

So `.` has to espaced to `\.` and space is written as `\s` as you might already know by now.`[A-Z]` refers to a group of uppercase charecters while `[a-z]` refers to a group of lowercase charecters obviously.

So this regex `(([A-Z].?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+)` will also match:

```
B. Jack
B.Jack Black
B Jack Black
B J Black
BJ Black
B.Jack Black
B.J.Black
B. Jack Black
```

Now, in addition to the `.` you see other characters like `?` which means match one or none,`*` which means match zero or more and `+` which we saw earlier which means match one or more and the expression `()` represents a group.You can match for individual groups in your code but the values maybe null if there was no match found for the group.

Now for the initials at the end `(([A-Z][a-z]+\.?\s?)+([A-Z]\.?\s?)*)` will match everything the first regex matches and will also match:

```
Jack B
Jack B.
Black Jack B.
Jack B
Black J.B
Black JB
Black J B
```

By now you must have already figured out that `[A-Z]\.?\s?` will match `A.` and `A`.So `([A-Z]\.?\s?)*` would zero of more occurances of these.

A combination of regex 2 and regex 3 using a `|` which represents `or` would match all of the inputs we have matched till now,but it would be too long.Instead you can add the regex matching the initials to both the start and end of the regular expression.Such an expression would be `(([A-Z]\.?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\.?\s?)+([A-Z]\.?\s?)*)`.This expression would match everything we have previously matched.

But what about `Black J Black` and `Black J. Black`.We currently have the ability to match any string that looks like `Black J B`,you could simply add `[a-z]*` to the group representing initials in the name at the end so it would look like `(A-Z\.?\s?[a-z]*)`.

This expression looks like `(([A-Z]\.?\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\.?\s?)+([A-Z]\.?\s?[a-z]*)*)`

I have also noted that sometimes names on applications and some other places are written completely using uppercase charcters for which the expression

```
([A-Z]\.?\s?)+
```

would work.